# Duda con Ejercico de Ciclos Anidados C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Buenas Tardes, en el siguiente ejercicio, si quiero por ejemplo atender a dos personas, al pedir los datos de la primera y lo que va a comprar no me arroja la factura, si no que la arroja con el ultimo o este caso el ultimo caso, ademas combina los datos y no lo hace uno por uno individual.

Cabe destacar, que falta por elaborar en el programa varios casos y ademas a lo ultimo mandar a imprimir lo total vendido y atendido, pero por los momentos esta duda no me deja continuar.

```
    #include "iostream"
    #include "stdio.h"
    #include "math.h"
    #include "stdlib.h"
    #include "iomanip"

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
    int i, n, cn = 0, combo, c1, c2, c3;
    float combo1 = 8500, combo2 = 11700, combo3 = 15000;
    float descuento = 0, subtotal, total;
    char nombre[30], carnet = 's';

    cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
    cout<<"\n\nCantidad de Personas para Atender: ";
    cin>>n;

    for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        cn++;
        system("cls");
        cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
        cout<<"\n\nNombre del Ciudadano: "<<cn;cout<<" ";
        cin>>nombre;
        cout<<"\nPosee Carnet de la Patria (S/N): ";
        cin>>carnet;

        if(carnet == 's' || carnet =='S')
        {
            system("cls");
            cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
            cout<<"\n\nCombos Disponibles: ";
            cout<<"\n\nCombo 1 (Bs. 8500)";
            cout<<"\nCombo 2 (Bs. 11700)";
            cout<<"\nCombo 3 (Bs. 15000)";
            cout<<"\n\nCombo a Comprar: ";
            cin>>combo;

            switch (combo)
            {
                case 1:

                system("cls");
                cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
                cout<<"\n\nCombo 1 (Bs. 8500)";
                cout<<"\n\nCantidad a Comprar: ";
                cin>>c1;

                subtotal = c1 * combo1;
                if(subtotal > 50000)
                    descuento = subtotal * 8.7/100;
                total = subtotal - descuento;

                system("cls");
                cout<<"< = = = C L A P Edo. T A C H I R A = = = >";
                cout<<"\n\n< - F A C T U R A - >";
                cout<<"\n\nCliente: "<<nombre;
                cout<<"\n\nSubtotal: Bs. "<<subtotal;
                cout<<"\nDescuento: Bs. -"<<descuento;
                cout<<"\n\nTotal a Pagar: Bs. "<<total;
                break;

                default:
                cout<<"Opcion Invalida, Intente Nuevamente";

            }

        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las variables se quedan con los valores anteriores siempre , dado que **no se igualan a `0` después de hacer las operaciones.** *(antes de volver al for)*

```
for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
{ 
 /* Demás código  if swicth */
 if(carnet == 's' || carnet =='S'){....}
 switch (combo){ .... }
 /* Después del if y  switch , Igualamos a 0 las variables para que no 
    se quedé con los valores  de las operaciones anteriores */
  subtotal =0; total=0;descuento=0;
}
```

Comment: Esto es Correcto ahora si hace bien los calculos, sin embargo todavia tengo un problema, en el que solamente imprime la factura cuando se trata del ultimo caso. Cuando al principio le digo que 2 personas, me pide los datos de la primera al momento de mostrar factura no lo hace si no que pasa a la siguiente persona  y ahí si me arroja la factura de esta ultima. Como podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Funciona correctamente su programa. la única razón que se me ocurre que pase esto , es que al momento de seleccionar el combo . se elija una opción diferente a 1.

Comment: Sigue igual, imprime la factura es del ultimo cliente, y no uno por uno... La idea es que por cada cliente que vaya procesando me muestre su factura, uno por uno.

Comment: Verificar aquí su código : https://repl.it/HBfX/0

Comment: Efectivamente compilando con esta web va de maravilla, caso contrario con el Zinjai, el cual estoy usando para compilarlo, no lo hace de este modo. El system("cls") no lo reconoce el REPL.IT algun otro que funcione? Saludos!